How does rendering of client component which is a child of server component in nextjs happen
I have a server component and a client component in the following manner
<Server> 
   <Client></Client>
</Server>

And i subsequently navigate between this route and other route (Lets say the duration of Router cache has exceeded before I come back to this route). So request will be made to the server will that request also include entire client component ??
